Table Alignment in CKEditor
In Craft CMS, I installed the CKEditor plugin and added it to a field. Now, when I add a table, it always appears centered. I want to align the table to the left, right, or center. I am looking for table alignment, not text alignment, which is already working well.
enter image description here.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
